# Application updates check issue

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to find a way to let my users find out if an update exist.
what i'm trying to do is to connect my user to my Dropbox an get the current
update version from it.

here is my code (wich is not really mine...)

```
 Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(" https://www.dropbox.com/s/MyDropBox/Version.txt?dl=0")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

    If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
        MsgBox("You are up todate!")
    Else
        MsgBox("You are not up todate!")
    End If
```

My problam is that no matter what i'm getting the msg "You are not up todate!".

Can anyone tell me why?

BTW the address to my dropbox changed by me before publishing my question to "MyDropbox"

Comment: What is the value of newestversion?

Comment: You can store all the informations in a text file and read it without logging on Dropbox.

Comment: Similar to @Malcor, show the value of newestversion and currentversion and then you may see where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

There's the reasons why your code **isn't appropriate** :

- The process is **too long**,
- It returns **too much text for nothing**,
- You don't use the **correct Dropbox type of link**,
- And **apparently, the returned text doesn't contain the text you want** (the file content).

So, instead of using this type of link : `https://www.dropbox.com/s/MyDropBox/Version.txt?dl=0`, **you should use this one** : `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/MyDropBox/Version.txt?dl=0` which **display the raw content** of the file.

There's the code I'm using in one of my softwares :

It requires a `BackgroundWorker` (required to don't freeze the UI) and a `Button`.

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Private UpdateLink As String = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5ogqwr9kc31r61w/Update.txt?dl=0"
    Private InstalledVersion As String = Application.ProductVersion
    Private UpToDate As String = "UpToDate"
    Private Outdated As String = "Outdated"
    Private LatestVersion As String
    Private MAJ As New WebClient

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Try
            'Original link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ogqwr9kc31r61w/Update.txt?dl=0
            'But it redirects to the file with Dropbox online interface.
            'If you replace "www.dropbox" by "dl.dropboxusercontent", the new link will redirect to the raw text.
            'New link is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5ogqwr9kc31r61w/Update.txt?dl=0

            LatestVersion = MAJ.DownloadString(UpdateLink)

            If LatestVersion.Contains(InstalledVersion) Then
                e.Result = UpToDate
            Else
                e.Result = Outdated
            End If

            MAJ.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            e.Result = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Button1.Enabled = True

        Select Case e.Result
            Case UpToDate
                MsgBox("It's up to date (Latest : " & LatestVersion & ", Installed : " & InstalledVersion & ")")
            Case Outdated
                MsgBox("It's outdated (Latest : " & LatestVersion & ", Installed : " & InstalledVersion & ")")
            Case Else
                MsgBox(e.Result)
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Your `Update.txt` file can contain only the latest version.

**Edit :** The advantage with the BackgroundWorker is that it won't freeze the UI. So, in example, you can add a `ProgressBar`.

Example of improvement :

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Try
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(30)

            'Original link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ogqwr9kc31r61w/Update.txt?dl=0
            'But it redirects to the file with Dropbox online interface.
            'If you replace "www.dropbox" by "dl.dropboxusercontent", the new link will redirect to the raw text.
            'New link is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5ogqwr9kc31r61w/Update.txt?dl=0

            LatestVersion = MAJ.DownloadString(UpdateLink)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(80)

            If LatestVersion.Contains(InstalledVersion) Then
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                e.Result = UpToDate
            Else
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                e.Result = Outdated
            End If

            MAJ.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            e.Result = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
```

To change the ProgressBar Value :

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
```

And you must set the BackgroundWorker `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `True`.