# How to make a VB program update automatically from dropbox

Tags: vb.net, dropbox, auto-update

I have followed tutorials on how to do this, but they never seem to work and I can't contact the creators of the tutorials. I just need to know how to make my program check if it has an update from dropbox and then download it, if it is a newer version. The code will be ran on the startup of the program. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, the program is a VB Form.

This is the layout I'm hoping for.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'check for update
    If update = True Then
        MsgBox("Update available, downloading")
        'download update
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you handling versions? A file could be two weeks old or two minutes old. If it isn't newer than what you've already got it is not an update.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32117061/3970387), it may help you...

Comment: Thanks Drarig29 that should work, I'm to tired to implement it today though, hopefully it will work fine thanks again.